# How to stack submatrices of a matrix to reduce dimensionality

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions

I couldn't find a good solution for this:

I have a matrix of this size: *60x10x3*

And I want to transform it into a matrix of this size: *600x3*

Basically I want to stack the 10 matrices with the dimension *60x3* next to each other in the first dimension.

How can I achieve that elegantly in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I don't understand what the intended output is, but here are two different ways to achieve it. I added the loop to create different numbers so the results can be studied.

**Method 1 - Stack Vertically or Horizontally**

```
s = zeros(60,10,3);
for x = 1:9
    s(:,x,:) = x;
end
t = reshape(s, 600, 3); %vert
u = t'; %hori
```

**Method 2 - Stack 3rd dimension Vertically or horizontally**

```
s = zeros(60,10,3);
for x = 1:9
    s(:,x,:) = x;
end
t = [s(:,:,1) , s(:,:,2), s(:,:,3)]; % hori
t = [s(:,:,1) ; s(:,:,2); s(:,:,3)]; % vert
```

Hope it helps, but this shows that there are multiple ways to achieve the same output in Matlab. Very powerful tool indeed.

Comment: I think I even found an (quite ugly) solution myself, that's why I am asking, thanks for showing different possibilities.
Basically I have 10 sets of 60 measurements over time. I see those 10 sets as independent measurements. Basically 600 data points, thus I don't need to separate them logically

Answer (score 1):

```
A = rand(60, 10, 3);
B = reshape(A, [], size(A, 3));
```

should work for any dimensions of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that

> stack[s] the 10 matrices with the dimension 60x3 next to each other in the first dimension.

```
a = rand(60,3,10);
% swap the 2nd and 3rd dimention
b = permute(a,[1,3,2]);
% condense to 2d
c = b(:,:);
% reshape x, y and z seperately so each group of 60 xs/ys/zs appends to the end of the previous group
x=reshape(c(:,1:3:end),[],1);
y=reshape(c(:,2:3:end),[],1);
z=reshape(c(:,3:3:end),[],1);
% condense to one 600*3 matrix
d = [x y z];
```